# Integral of $16/(1-\cos8x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Can someone please help me with this question:

$$ \int \ \frac{16}{1-\cos8x} \ \ dx  \ \ . $$

I tried substitution by letting $u=1-\cos8x$, it got messy after the substitution. I used the identities rules, it still got messy. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Please let me know if I have edited your text properly.  You should use LaTeX or MathJax here to make your math expressions legible.

Comment: @DavidH I tried substitution by letting u=1-cos8x, it got messy after the substitution. I used the identities rules, it still got messy. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, I will use LaTeX from now. This is my first time. Thank you.

Comment: You can use something referred to as the "Weierstrass substitution" (which he apparently had nothing to do with): see, for instance, http://jekyll.math.byuh.edu/courses/m113/handouts/weierstrass.pdf .

Answer (score 4):

The most direct way is probably to multiply and divide by $1+\cos8x$. Then you get
$$
16\,\int\,\frac{1+\cos8x}{1-\cos^28x}\,dx=16\,\int\,\frac{1}{1-\cos^28x}\,dx+16\,\int\,\frac{\cos8x}{1-\cos^28x}\,dx\\
=16\,\int\,\frac{1}{\sin^28x}\,dx+16\,\int\,\frac{\cos8x}{\sin^28x}\,dx,
$$
both easy.

Answer (score 4):

Letting $\theta=8x$, the integral becomes

$$\int\frac{16\,dx}{1-\cos{8x}}=2\int\frac{d\theta}{1-\cos{\theta}}.$$

The integral $\int\frac{d\theta}{1-\cos{\theta}}$ can be solved using [the world's sneakiest substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution): $t=\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$. Under this substitution,

$$\int\frac{d\theta}{1-\cos{\theta}}=\int\frac{dt}{t^2}=-\frac{1}{t}+constant=-\cot{\frac{\theta}{2}}+constant.$$

Altogether,

$$\int\frac{16\,dx}{1-\cos{8x}}=-2\cot{4x}.$$

Comment: Awesome link. +1

Comment: @wgrenard Thank you. You might also want to check out RecklessReckoner's linked pdf in the comments above.

Comment: Your result is what WolframAlpha produces.  It is the same as the anti-derivative found by **Martin Argerami** and **Nameless** through the identity $$ \ \cot  \frac{\theta}{2} \ = \ \frac{1 \ + \ \cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \ = \ \csc \theta \ + \ \cot \theta \ \ . $$

Answer (score 4):

First let $u = 8x$ and then $du = 8dx.$ So your integral becomes

\begin{align}
\int\frac{2}{1 - \cos u} \cdot \frac{1 + \cos u}{ 1 + \cos u} du &= \int \frac{2(1 + \cos u)}{1 - \cos^2 u} du \\
&= \int \frac{  2(1 + \cos u)}{\sin^2 u} du\\
&= \int 2(\csc^2 u + \cot u \csc u) du \\
&=-2\cot u - 2\csc u + C\\
&=-2(\cot 8x + \csc 8x) + C
\end{align}

Comment: You may wish to re-examine your last couple steps... (I wasn't the downvoter.)

Comment: My internet keeps going out right now so it was difficult for me to make edits. I noticed I accidentally multiplied $2$ instead of dividing initially, but that has been corrected and that was the only mistake.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int{16 \over 1 - \cos\pars{8x}}\,\dd x}&=
16\int{\dd x\over 2\sin^{2}\pars{4x}}
=8\int\csc^{2}\pars{4x}\,\dd x
=8\bracks{-\,{\cot\pars{4x} \over 4}}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large-2\cot\pars{4x}} + \mbox{a constant} 
\end{align}